# How to integrate google places API array of results with knockout?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, knockout.js

I am trying to create a Google Maps application that uses the Places API to add markers of interesting places in the map as well as populating a list using knockout.js.

So far, I managed to populate the map with the locations using the following code:

```
'use strict'

// Google Maps API and Places library functions to start the map
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var coimbra = new google.maps.LatLng(40.209658,-8.419721);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: coimbra,
    zoom: 18,
    disableDefaultUI: true
  });

  // Request for places library for nearby places of interest
  // Most of the code comes from the google Maps API documentation
  var request = {
    location: coimbra,
    radius: '400',
    types: ['store', 'café','food', 'bar']
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

// Function that receives the results of the callback function and adds the markers to the map
function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });
}
```

I also have the following HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Neighbourhood Map</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <script src='js/knockout-3.4.0.js'></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src='js/app.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="search-bar">
    <form class='search'>
      <input placeholder="Filter results by name" autofocus>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <ul class="list-places">
      <li class="place"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script async defer src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBXeGehzCayzqOJWG56XYrst22ZQ-hUzJA&libraries=places&callback=initialize'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

From the Knockout documentation, it seems I can populate the list by setting the array that comes from the places API into a `ko.observableArray` and then use the respective databinds in the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags to populate a list with all the locations found by the API.

My main doubt however is how to access that array to set it into a `ko.observableArray`:

Should I do something like this or is there any other way I am missing?

```
function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var results = ko.observableArray(results);
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code isn't clear, especially the way you double-use `results` and don't use `place`. Have you defined a viewmodel?

Comment: I mainly got the code snippets for the places API and the Map from the official google map documentation. I will define a viewmodel for populating the list and adding a search bar but I was also advised to leave everything related with google maps out of the viewmodel and that is part of my confusion: how to use an array (with the places) you obtain from using the places API with the callback function with the viewmodel.

Comment: You're going to need a custom binding handler for map functions. There is one here, http://testasoftware.com/steve/blog/knockout-binding-handler-for-google-maps/, but I do not know whether it will suit your needs. If you don't know what a custom binding handler is or why you would need one, let me know and I'll put together an explainer as an answer.

Comment: If you could give me an explanation and it does not steal too much of your time, I would be really glad :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick overview of how Knockout works: you have a view, Knockout, and a viewmodel. The view is the DOM: all the stuff that a user will see. The viewmodel is a collection of variables that represent all possible states of the view, including data and control states (like what checkboxes are checked). Knockout sits between the view and the viewmodel, and its purpose is to make sure they are in sync: changes in the view get reflected in the viewmodel, and vice-versa. This way, you never have to mess with the DOM.

Binding handlers belong to Knockout. They tell Knockout how to synchronize particular pieces of the view with their corresponding elements in the viewmodel. Handlers for the basic, common DOM elements are included, but when you get a complex element like those in the Google Maps kit, there's no pre-written binding.

In a binding handler, you have access to both the DOM element and the viewmodel variables that are bound to it, so that you can make their changes reflect in each other.

All that said, it looks to me like your array-fetching is a pure-data operation that doesn't involve the DOM, so you can probably just do

```
function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    myArrayOfResults(results);
  }
}
```

somewhere in your viewmodel code, where `myArrayOfResults` is an observableArray defined in your viewmodel.

If you have not been through the [Knockout tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com), it is worth your time. When you get to the point that you need to write a binding handler, the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) covers that, too. There is also [this article](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html) for some more well-rounded instruction.

Comment: Many thanks Roy, your explanation helped me a lot :)